# Accessing a button of a table view from other view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, object

How can i access a button which is present in a view ,from any other view.Let me elaborate i have two view controller A and B.in view A i have a button inside table view  say button1 .I want to access that button inside the table view from my other view.Please help.I tried creating an object of class A and then write [objA.tableview button1 then i set image ] but it hasnt worked .Please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this give a tag to your button (make sure it is unique).

Let say your button has tag 45; and you have made it in your table view.

Now in another method you want to use your that button like this:-

```
-(void)deletePostMethod
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:49];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    NSLog(@"button=%@",button);
}
```

Edited Answer:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tablefirst cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // I  have added a button in my table view in first row
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePostMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.tag=579;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
    }
        return cell;
}
```

On that button click method

```
-(void)deletePostMethod
{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:579];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    NSLog(@"button=%@",button);
}
```

After clicking this button button background color set to red.

Comment: @christina I hope It will help you

Comment: i am not able to understand please say in detail,i have a table view in one view and a table view in other view how can i access a uibutton preset in table view in one view from the other view

Comment: you only have to create a button with a unique tag where ever let assume you have created in your 1table view. Now where ever you want to access that button use this line UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:49];
It will give reference to your that button.And now you can do what ever you wnat to do in button like image change or something.

Comment: do i have to write self.view or myclassname.view

Comment: or rather table view as that button is inside table view

Comment: -(void)ClickTo1:(id)sender
{
 // TableView2ViewController *table2=[[TableView2ViewController alloc]init];
 
 //table2.tableView=self.tableView1;
 if ([sender tag]==10) {
  UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  //[[[table2 tableView ]button2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  
 }
 
 
 
}

Comment: this is what i am trying to do ,i created a button wiht tag 1 in first view controller

Comment: but please make sure there are two table view and i am tying to access button of one table view from teh click of a button in anothr table view

Comment: but i am not writing that click event in that view i am writing that method in another view

Comment: can i write this deletePost method in other view.will this work

Comment: i am in view2 table view and when i click a button in this table view then i want to access button frm table view in view 1,tell me please how to do this

Comment: @Christina I have given you an idea dear you can you implement this.But its totally up to you how to do according to your exact requirement.I think you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `viewControllers` property to access the list of all `UIViewController` in your navigation stack.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers

NSArray* allController = self.navigationController.viewControllers ;

for(UIViewController* myAController in  allController)
{
         if( [myAController isMemberOfClass])
         {
              //Here Now you have the A controller 
              MyViewAController*  myATempController =  (MyViewAController*)myAController;

             //Now you could access the property of your A Controller.
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make your button a property of the view controller so that you can just access it by name.

In your interface file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

    UIButton* myButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton* myButton;

@end
```

In your implementation file:

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myButton;

@end
```

Then you can just use `aViewController.myButton` to get your button.